# Accepting/Showing 2 digit integers on Assembly using NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, integer-arithmetic

I'm currently working on a Assembly project. The code works fine on adding 1 digit integer with 1 digit sum, but when I entered 2 digit integers the program will either exit or return no input.
This is my work so far:

```
SYS_EXIT  equ 1
SYS_READ  equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
STDIN     equ 0
STDOUT    equ 1

segment .data

    msg1 db "Enter the first digit: ",0xA, 0xD
    len1 equ $- msg1

    msg2 db "Please second digit: "  ,0xA, 0xD
    len2 equ $- msg2

    msg3 db "The sum is "
    len3 equ $- msg3

segment .bss

    num1 resb 255
    num2 resb 255
    res  resb 255
    
section .text

    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, msg1
    mov edx, len1
    int 0x80

    mov eax, SYS_READ
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov ecx, num1
    mov edx, 255
    int 0x80

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, msg2
    mov edx, len2
    int 0x80

    mov eax, SYS_READ
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov ecx, num2
    mov edx, 255
    int 0x80

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, msg3
    mov edx, len3
    int 0x80

    mov eax, [num1]
    sub eax, '0'
    mov ebx, [num2]
    sub ebx, '0'

    add eax, ebx
    add eax, '0'


    mov [res], eax

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, res
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80


;move eax, SYS_EXIT
;int 0x80

exit:
    mov eax, SYS_EXIT
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

This is my sample input:

> Please enter first digit: 5
>
> Please second digit: 2
>
> The sum is: 7

My problem is this:

> Please enter first digit: 5
>
> Please second digit: 5
>
> The sum is:

The sum returns 0.

Comment: You convert a number to a digit by adding `'0'`. That works fine for 0..9, but 10 isn't a single digit. You will have to split it up and display `'1'` and `'0'` separately.

Comment: How? i'm still a newbie here, trying to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: You do know how to do it by hand. You write thousands, hundreds, tens etc separately. Repeat the same procedure. Just think how you can make `13` into `1` and `3`.

Comment: Returning input is a tough discipline, usually anything returned is considered output (sarcastic joke, I know, I'm sorry, I can't resist). To format an base 10 integer, for a newbie it may be easiest to allocate long enough buffer of chars, and then do char=number mod 10, number = number/10, repeat when number != 0. Then print the buffer from end to start char by char (`+'0'`). There's lot of SO questions about this, just search for sources, if you don't want to try it on your own (you probably should, it's not that difficult, and it's good opportunity to study `DIV` instruction).